# MVC 2 how to go to url without redirecting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, logout, urlrequest

Is there a way to go to a url without redirecting to it? Basically I want to call a url from within my application in the background so it can logout a reliant party.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: What? Can you say that in English please? - Without understanding you can always call `domain.com/account/LogOut` and that will clear the current credentials assigned to the user.

Comment: @balexandre: if you do that then your application will be directed to that page, I want to go to the url without being redirected to it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do **does not compete us to answer** as it's directly related to your own Authentication implementation.

A normal **ASP.NET Authentication** based in Forms Authentication you will need **always to lunch the url from a browser** as it is there that relies the Authentication given.

You can **give yourself a try** by  opening your website and log in into it, after that, open other browser brand (not browser window) into your application url... you will see that you also **need to login again** as the Authentication is hook up into the first browser.

It's Up to you as Application Architect to make this by **implementing another way of authentication**, normally in this kind'a cases, this happend when consuming web services where you need a **authentication code** first (given by calling a Login method) and that code is always needed to be appended to the body or header **of any call to the system**.

This way you can easily remove the authentication code and all procedure calls will fail.

As said, this is not up to us, it's up to you to create the **correct Authentication Layer**.

---

from your comment

it's as simple as using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) object

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient ();
 string reply = client.DownloadString (address);
```

Comment: you are right in that it is my authentication system but my question is not related to how my authentication works but how I can call a url in the background.  You do not need to know or care about my authentocation system, I just added that part for some background info.

Comment: If it's just for that, you should just ask for that! Plenty of tutorials around with that. You can either use `HttpWebRequest` or `WebClient`

Comment: I did ask for that "Basically I want to call a url from within my application in the background".

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to transfer to a new url request you can still use

```
Server.TransferRequest()
```

The problem with this is that by not using a redirect the browsers address bar will not reflect the fact that you have moved their request to another URL.

Comment: I want the call to happen in the background so that it logs out of a reliant party.

Answer (score 0):

To have the client visit a given URL in the background you should either make an AJAX call to it or possibly have an image with an src of your logout url (though you'd have to make sure that you return a FileResult of your image too). This is how most analytics packages call to their relevant urls in the background.

The problem here though is that neither is 100% reliable, turn off javascript or images on your browser and these results fail.

From what you've said I think what you're after is for a user to continue to any of a variety of pages rather than a specific logout page. If this is indeed the case your best solution is in fact a double redirect.

Have your application redirect to your logout url but before hand put the url of the page you want them to go to into tempdata. Then in the actionresult for the logout page you can do your logging out as required and return a redirect to the url from tempdata.